# How to hide TabBar from UITabBarController when any other UIViewController is pushed to stack

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

How to hide TabBar when any UIViewController is pushed

I have written following code in all four **child UIViewController of UITabBarController**

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

       self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
 }

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
       self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

But above code is not working fine how to hide TabBar from UITabBarController when any other UIViewController is pushed to stack

In other terms I want to hide TabBar when any view is pushed above UITabBarController and want to show it back when user is back on RootViewController

Comment: is the code above part of a superclass all your other classes inherit from?

Comment: child UIViewController of UITabBarController

Comment: @amodkanthe kindly check my answer

Comment: thanks found same solution after doing some research :)

Comment: @amodkanthe great bro

Comment: hide bottom bar on push ticked worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide tabbar controller in your ChildViewController :

- If you are using Storyboard than simply go select that childViewController on which you need to hide the Tabbar & go to inspector on right panel. Set the Bottombar to none. (It will be Inferred By default (See Screenshot))

[image]

- If you do so there is nothing you needs to write into the code. It will work automatically.

Hope this helps to everyone.